# Setting up gunicorn and supervisor for django server

Tags: python, django, server, gunicorn

I am trying to get my server up and running with gunicorn and supervisor.
Managed to get it upp with this command:

```
$ gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind 192.168.1.130:8000
```

After this I made a gunicorn_init.bash file. I got the code from several tutorials. So guess it's a common way to set up gunicorn and supervisor. The code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="project"                                                   # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/username/projects/project                    # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/username/.venvs/project/run/gunicorn.sock     # We will communicate using this unix socket
USER=username                                              # the user to run as
GROUP=username                                             # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=1                                                   # how many worker processes shoul Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.production               # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=project.wsgi                                  # WSGI module name
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/username/.venvs/project/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exsist

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start yout Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use daemon)

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_UNICORN}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

This only gives me exception is worker process like this:

```
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30218] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30218] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30218] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/username/.venvs/project/run/gunicorn.sock (30218)
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30218] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30223] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30223
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30223] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.venvs/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/username/.venvs/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/username/.venvs/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/username/.venvs/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/username/.venvs/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/username/.venvs/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/username/.venvs/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ValueError: Empty module name
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30223] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 30223)
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30218] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-10-15 12:35:37 +0200] [30218] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I read and watched tutorials. Gone in to docs, trying to figure out why it' not working when calling the gunicorn-bash file.

Any pointers in right direction is much appreciated now. I've been stuck for quite some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an inconsistent variable. At the top of the script you define `DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE`, but in the call to gunicorn you are using `DJANGO_WSGI_UNICORN` which does not exist. Make sure you use the same name.

Comment: The amount of times I read through the code and didn't see this. Thanks Daniel aka eagle eye

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as an indication to future searchers that it solved your problem.